# Chvatal-Erdos theorem proof (that is hamiltonian)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Theorem. If G is hamiltonian then, for **every** nonempty proper subset $S$ of $V(G)$, we have:
$k(G-S) \le |S|$

I need to proof that it works in the opposite direction. That If I find a subset $S$ that doesn't meet the theorem condition I will be able to tell/conclude that this particular graph doesn't have a hamilton cycle/circut.

I'm thinking about the word "every" that is in the therorem. Is it enough to point out, that because of this word it will work like I've described above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contrapositive of that theorem is:

> If there exists a nonempty proper subset $S$ of $V(G)$ such that $k(G-S)>|S|$, then $G$ is not Hamiltonian.

So the answer to your question is [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).